# Validate time within a range

Tags: asp.net, validation, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a TextBox and AjaxControlToolkit MaskedEditExtender for users to enter a time. The control is bound to a timespan property in code (and time(7) column in SQL Server). The requirement is to ensure that all times are between 1800h and 0000h (it's for bat recording). Can anyone suggest how to use the MaskedEditValidator to ensure the time entered is in this range?

My code so far:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmergenceTime" runat="server"  CssClass="formInput"
    Text='<%# Eval("EmergenceTime", "{0:hh\:mm}") %>' />
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeEmergenceTime" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="txtEmergenceTime" Mask="99:99" MaskType="Time"
    AutoComplete="false" AutoCompleteValue="0"/>
<asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="valEmergenceTime" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Emergence time must be between 18:00 and 00:00"
    CssClass="error" ControlToValidate="txtEmergenceTime"
    ValidationGroup="roostCount">*</asp:MaskedEditValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may set interval from 18:00 to 23:59 and utilize MaskedEditValidato's `MinimumValue` and `MaximumValue` properties. Or you can define `ClientValidationFunction` property for validator extender and use custom validation

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. The syntax for my server control above wasn't quite right (e.g. no ControlExtender property). But, even after fixing that, I couldn't get an error message to display using MinimumValue and MaximumValue - though it did display for invalid times e.g. 18:99 and did block updating my form when I entered values out of range. Nor could I get the error messages to display in my validation summary. It looks like a lot of people have problems with this validation control so I may go for a vanilla CustomValidator instead (and update question if successful).